# Can I use SIM command line for local deployments?

Tags: sim

I want to use [SIM](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Instance-Manager/releases) in my local deployment scripts but I cannot figure out where to find the tool. I expected it to be here, but the `Apps` folder is empty:

```
%appdata%\Sitecore\Sitecore Instance manager\Apps\SIMCMD\sim.exe
```

I found `SIM.Tool.exe`under the following (quite strange) path, but that is just a UI tool launcher:

```
%AppData%\Local\Apps\2.0\3THNC6J1.QKG\1JZ9G8ZG.8MR\sim...tion_abafaebf7cc9a2b2_0001.0005_f7e46463611ea296
```

Any idea if the command line tool is still supported?
My version: SIM 1.5.0.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very simple to run **SIMCMD** (Command Line version of SIM):

1. Open SIM
2. Click Bundled Tools - Command Line
3. Voilà

[image]

**N.B.** Step 2 here simply downloads latest version from [dl.sitecore.net](http://dl.sitecore.net/updater/1.1/simcmd/simcmd.zip)

**Note** even though it is available in Release version, this feature is still kind of experimental and does not support all functions of full version. So I highly recommend to check the source code of the commands before using them in (pre-)production environment.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks. For now the only limitation I noticed is that I cannot specify the host name and the default value is differ from the one suggested by UI tool. I described this behavior [here](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Instance-Manager/issues/19#issuecomment-307301327).

Comment: I don't see this option in bundled tools

Answer (score 3):

## SIM is a click-once application

You can launch it from command line, but it's not so obvious how. There are a couple of ways to launch it. One would be to invoke something like iexplore.exe, pointing it to the URL of the SIM installation.

My preferred method is launching it via the local `.appref-ms` file. You find it like this:

Open up "Start", find SIM.

[image]

Right click and Open File Location.

[image]

In this folder, you will find your `.appref-ms` file. This is what you need to launch from your command line.

[image]

## Automated installation from the command line

Is planned for SIM 2.0. Reference: https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Instance-Manager/issues/18

### But there is another way.

Using the [Hedgehog.Tds.Build.Sim.Console](https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/BuildExtensions/tree/master/Hedgehog.Tds.Build.Sim.Console), which is a tool meant specifically to handle this current shortcoming.

Also blogged about by Jeremy Davis here: [HOW DID I MISS THIS BIT OF SIM AUTOMATION?](https://jermdavis.wordpress.com/2015/04/13/how-did-i-miss-this-bit-of-sim-automation/)

Example use:

```
Hedgehog.Tds.Build.Sim.Console.exe install
  "InstanceName:demo.tds"
  "InstanceDirectory:c:\sitecore"
  "RepoDirectory:c:\sitecorerepo"
  "RepoFile:Sitecore 7.1 rev. 130926.zip"
  "ConnectionString:Data Source=.;User ID=sitecore;Password=sitecore123"
  "AppPoolIdentity:NetworkService"
  "LicencePath:C:\Sitecore\license.xml"
```

Comment: Yep, but that just launches the UI app... I'd like to use the tool to install instances from the scripts.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Looks like the Hedgehog tool is quite outdated... no commits since 2014.. 
It fails trying to locate `SIM.Kernel.Instances.dll`, probably the obsolete one; I can find only `SIM.Instances.dll` in the SIM directory.

Comment: It appeared that the SIM CLI [needs to be downloaded independently](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/6063/272). It was a surprise to me but it does exactly what I need.