# Can we invoke sitecore SIM from MSbuild?

Tags: automation

I'm looking to automate my local dev environment without using TDS and want to make use of sitecore SIM , powershell or msbuild to do all my stuff.

**One time Setup**
Idea is to create one bat file which will take care following:-

```
1. Install sitecore instance using sitecore SIM
2. Install Sitecore packages (CMS items/templates etc)
3. Application level configurations and setting.
```

**Incremental** step would be to publish solution on top of it...as part of ongoing development. I want to keep less dependency on tds or other tool. Want to keep it simple so as tosetup dev local environment in any developer machine.

Comment: I think you are looking for this. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6052/can-i-use-sim-command-line-for-local-deployments. I have used this several times in the past. https://github.com/patrickperrone/Sitecore-PowerShell-Installer